# Calibrating CatBoostClassifier produces worse results

Tags: probability, multi-class, calibration, scoring-rules, catboost

I'm performing multiclass probability prediction using CatBoostClassifier on a dataset with ~4000 rows, 13 features, 4 target classes. Dataset has outliers, but it is balanced.

For this task I'm using CatBoostClassifier with `objective=MultiClass`, `eval_metric='MultiClass'`, `num_classes=4`

Here are my steps in training and evaluating the model:
I'm using `random_state=42` while splitting data and as a CatBoost parameter during both hyperparameters tuning and model evaluation with best found hyperparameters.
My model training and evaluation steps:

1. Split data into train, val, test sets in 0.7:0.15:0.15 proportion with stratification.
2. Perform hyperparameters tuning with Optuna, using LogLoss as an evaluation metric (training on train set, evaluating on val set) and performing early stopping rounds using `(X_val, y_val)` as model's `eval_set` during hyperparameters tuning.
3. Fit model with best found hyperparameters on train set (`model.fit(X_train, y_train)`)
4. Calibrate unfitted model using sklearn's `CalibratedClassifierCV` with `cv=10`
5. Predict probabilities on `X_train` and `X_test`: `model.predict_proba(X_train)` and `model.predict_proba(X_test)`
6. Compare metrics on train and test set

My results:

| Calibration | Train Log Loss | Test Log Loss | Train AUC-ROC | Test AUC-ROC | Train Brier Score | Test Brier Score | Train ECE | Test ECE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Uncalibrated | 0.34 | **0.55** | 0.982 | **0.942** | 0.071 | 0.085 | 0.045 | **0.024** |
| Sigmoid | 0.38 | 0.57 | 0.982 | 0.941 | 0.070 | **0.084** | 0.054 | 0.030 |
| Isotonic | 0.33 | 0.65 | 0.982 | 0.941 | 0.071 | 0.086 | 0.039 | 0.028 |

[image: reliability_diagram]
[image: probability_histogram]

**So from the LogLoss, Brier Score and ECE it seems like the classifier became worse overall after calibration. Is this normal?**

My model is overfitting, but I was suggested that [this amount of overfitting is acceptable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643612/is-my-model-overfitting-or-is-my-training-process-wrong)(my task is predicting probabilities of songs belonging to 4 mood categories)

Assuming calibration is always supposed to make probability predictions better and these results are not normal, I suspect that either my model overfits too much, or my calculations of Brier Score and ECE are wrong (though it doesn't explain worse LogLoss, I used sklearn's function to calculate that)

Here are implementations of Brier score and ECE I used:

```py
def calculate_brier_score(true_labels, predicted_probabilities):

    true_labels = np.array(true_labels)
    predicted_probabilities = np.array(predicted_probabilities)

    num_samples, num_classes = predicted_probabilities.shape

    one_hot_true = np.eye(len(predicted_probabilities[0]))[true_labels]
    probs_true = predicted_probabilities[np.arange(len(true_labels)), true_labels]

    brier_score = np.mean((probs_true - 1) ** 2)  # Squared errors for true classes
    brier_score += np.mean(predicted_probabilities ** 2, axis=1)  # Squared predicted probs for other classes
    brier_score /= len(predicted_probabilities[0])  # Normalize by number of classes

    return np.mean(brier_score)
```

```py
def calculate_ece(y, proba, bins='fd'):
    # Get number of classes
    num_classes = proba.shape[1]

    ece_sum = 0.0
    for class_idx in range(num_classes):
        bin_count, bin_edges = np.histogram(proba[:, class_idx], bins=bins)
        n_bins = len(bin_count)
        bin_edges[0] -= 1e-8  # because left edge is not included
        bin_id = np.digitize(proba[:, class_idx], bin_edges, right=True) - 1
        bin_ysum = np.bincount(bin_id, weights=y == class_idx, minlength=n_bins)
        bin_probasum = np.bincount(bin_id, weights=proba[:, class_idx], minlength=n_bins)
        bin_ymean = np.divide(bin_ysum, bin_count, out=np.zeros(n_bins), where=bin_count > 0)
        bin_probamean = np.divide(bin_probasum, bin_count, out=np.zeros(n_bins), where=bin_count > 0)
        ece = np.abs((bin_probamean - bin_ymean) * bin_count).sum() / len(proba)
        ece_sum += ece

    # Calculate average ECE across all classes
    average_ece = ece_sum / num_classes
    return average_ece
```

Comment: Something is off with your Brier score calculations. You compute the mean three times and `one_hot_true` is never used.

Comment: Can you try varying the random state and see how much these metrics change across 100 runs? I do wonder if we're looking at difference in noise in comparing the calibrated loss vs non-calibrated.

Comment: @CliffAB stupid qustion, but should I change random state in both train_test_split and CatBoost parameters? Also should I perform these 100 runs after hyperparameters tuning or including the tuning?